# how to apply multiple filters wordpress rest api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I need to retrieve wordpress posts on the basis of more than 1 filter.
e.g on the basis of category_name and title of the post inside the same category.

I'm using below url:

```
localhost:8000/wordpressTest/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[category_name]=test_categroy&?filter[title]=product_title
```

I'm getting all the posts under this category rather than single post. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrive posts in one category?

filter parameter is removed in WP REST API v2. since WP version 4.7

If you want to retrive post in the same category you can use this url

```
localhost:8000/wordpressTest/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?search=title&categories=1
```

Change the category id and keyword based on your case. 
Hope it helps

Comment: Its searching the keyword all over the post, if keyword is present anywhere in any post , its returning all of them. I've tried 'slug' as the key. Its giving proper results now.